# Filtering Object based on user input using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a data Object and based on the records I am generating a table. In that table, I am giving some options to the users to filer it out like below.

I have used the `$.grep` to filter the items. If you look at my code I have used the `$.grep` for each and every element and finally displaying the table. Look at the below code.

```
 var dataArray = {
"rooms": [
{"name":"1001","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
{"name":"1002","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
{"name":"1003","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
{"name":"1004","type":"Double","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
{"name":"1005","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1006","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1007","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
{"name":"1008","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
{"name":"1009","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
{"name":"1010","type":"Double","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":true,"ref":false},
{"name":"1011","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
{"name":"1012","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
{"name":"1013","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1014","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1015","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
{"name":"1016","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1017","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":false,"ref":false},
{"name":"1018","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":false,"ref":true}
]}

$("#roomTypeSelect").on('change', function(){updateTableView()});
    $('#checkAvailable, #checkAC, #checkTV, #checkRef').on('click', function(e){updateTableView(e);});
    function updateTableView(e) {
    console.log('called');
roomType = $('#roomTypeSelect option:selected').text();
        checkAvailable = $('#checkAvailable').prop('checked');
        checkAC = $('#checkAC').prop('checked');
        checkTV = $('#checkTV').prop('checked');
        checkRef = $('#checkRef').prop('checked');
        var lists = dataArray.rooms;

        if(roomType != 'Room Type') {
            lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
                return item.type == roomType;
            });
        }
        if(checkAvailable) {
            lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
                return item.status == 'Available';
            });
        }

        if(checkAC) {
            lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
                return item.ac == checkAC;
            });
        }
        if(checkTV) {
            lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
                return item.tv == checkTV;
            });
        }
        if(checkRef) {
            lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
                return item.ref == checkRef;
            });
        }

        var items = lists.map(function (item) {
            var ac = item.ac ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
            var tv = item.tv ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
            var ref = item.ref ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
            return '<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td class="'+item.status+'">'+item.status+'</td><td>'+item.type+'</td><td>'+ac+'</td><td>'+tv+'</td><td>'+ref+'</td></tr>';
        });
  console.log("ITEMS",items);
        $('table.results tbody').html(items);
    }
```

**Code Snippet**

```js
var dataArray = {
  "rooms": [
 {"name":"1001","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1002","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1003","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1004","type":"Double","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1005","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1006","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1007","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1008","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1009","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1010","type":"Double","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":true,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1011","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1012","type":"Single","status":"Occupied","ac":true,"tv":true,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1013","type":"Family","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1014","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1015","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":true},
 {"name":"1016","type":"Family","status":"Occupied","ac":false,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1017","type":"Double","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":false,"ref":false},
 {"name":"1018","type":"Single","status":"Available","ac":true,"tv":false,"ref":true}
  ]
 }

    $("#roomTypeSelect").on('change', function(){updateTableView()});
  $('#checkAvailable, #checkAC, #checkTV, #checkRef').on('click', function(e){updateTableView(e);});
  function updateTableView(e) {  
    roomType = $('#roomTypeSelect option:selected').text();
      checkAvailable = $('#checkAvailable').prop('checked');
      checkAC = $('#checkAC').prop('checked');
      checkTV = $('#checkTV').prop('checked');
      checkRef = $('#checkRef').prop('checked');
   var lists = dataArray.rooms;
      
   if(roomType != 'Room Type') {
       lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
        return item.type == roomType;
       });
   }
   if(checkAvailable) {
    lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
        return item.status == 'Available';
       });
   }
      
   if(checkAC) {
    lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
        return item.ac == checkAC;
       });
   }
   if(checkTV) {
    lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
        return item.tv == checkTV;
       });
   }
   if(checkRef) {
    lists = $.grep(lists, function (item) {
        return item.ref == checkRef;
       });
   }
      
   var items = lists.map(function (item) {
    var ac = item.ac ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var tv = item.tv ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var ref = item.ref ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
       return '<tr><td>'+item.name+'</td><td class="'+item.status+'">'+item.status+'</td><td>'+item.type+'</td><td>'+ac+'</td><td>'+tv+'</td><td>'+ref+'</td></tr>';
   });      
   $('table.results tbody').html(items);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="text-align:left; background-color:#ccc; border-right:1px solid #aaa; padding:2rem;">    
    <div class="form-group">    
     <select class="form-control" id="roomTypeSelect">
       <option>Room Type</option>
       <option>Single</option>
       <option>Double</option>
       <option>Family</option>
     </select>
       </div>
       <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAvailable">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAvailable">Available</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAC">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAC">AC</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkTV">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkTV">TV</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkRef">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkRef">Refridgerator</label>
    </div>
   </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="padding:2rem">
      <table class="table results">
      <thead>
     <tr>
       <th scope="col">Room#</th>
       <th scope="col">Status</th>
       <th scope="col">Type</th>
       <th scope="col">AC</th>
       <th scope="col">TV</th>
       <th scope="col">Refridgerator</th>      
     </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
     
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>    
    </div>
```

**QUESTION:** I feel that I have achieved the results using too many `$.grep` methods. Is there any simple way to do achieve this functionality?

Comment: @Andreas corrected it. kindly edit my question if you wan to use better words.

Comment: This question with _working code_ is a candidate for: https://codereview.stackexchange.com (but check the help as they have some very specific rules for questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, by changing it to a single grep statement like

```
    $.grep(lists, function(item) {
      return (roomType != 'Room Type' ? item.type == roomType : true) && (checkAvailable ? item.status == 'Available' : true) && (checkAC ? item.ac == checkAC : true) && (checkTV ?item.tv == checkTV : true) && (checkRef ? item.ref == checkRef : true)
    });
```

```js
var dataArray = {
  "rooms": [{
      "name": "1001",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1002",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1003",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1004",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1005",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1006",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1007",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1008",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1009",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1010",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1011",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1012",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1013",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1014",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1015",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1016",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1017",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1018",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    }
  ]
}

$("#roomTypeSelect").on('change', function() {
  updateTableView()
});
$('#checkAvailable, #checkAC, #checkTV, #checkRef').on('click', function(e) {
  updateTableView(e);
});

function updateTableView(e) {
  roomType = $('#roomTypeSelect option:selected').text();
  checkAvailable = $('#checkAvailable').prop('checked');
  checkAC = $('#checkAC').prop('checked');
  checkTV = $('#checkTV').prop('checked');
  checkRef = $('#checkRef').prop('checked');
  var lists = dataArray.rooms;

  lists = $.grep(lists, function(item) {
    return (roomType != 'Room Type' ? item.type == roomType : true) && (checkAvailable ? item.status == 'Available' : true) && (checkAC ? item.ac == checkAC : true) && (checkTV ? item.tv == checkTV : true) && (checkRef ? item.ref == checkRef : true)
  });

  var items = lists.map(function(item) {
    var ac = item.ac ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var tv = item.tv ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var ref = item.ref ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    return '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td class="' + item.status + '">' + item.status + '</td><td>' + item.type + '</td><td>' + ac + '</td><td>' + tv + '</td><td>' + ref + '</td></tr>';
  });
  $('table.results tbody').html(items);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="text-align:left; background-color:#ccc; border-right:1px solid #aaa; padding:2rem;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="roomTypeSelect">
       <option>Room Type</option>
       <option>Single</option>
       <option>Double</option>
       <option>Family</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAvailable">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAvailable">Available</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAC">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAC">AC</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkTV">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkTV">TV</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkRef">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkRef">Refridgerator</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="padding:2rem">
    <table class="table results">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Room#</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">AC</th>
          <th scope="col">TV</th>
          <th scope="col">Refridgerator</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `(roomType != 'Room Type' ? item.type == roomType : true)` this logic i missed when i tried with `&&` condition in grep. Thanks a lot. nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do all the comparisons inside the `$.grep`.

I've also refactored for using a naming convention for the checkboxes.

```js
var dataArray = {
  "rooms": [{
      "name": "1001",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1002",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1003",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1004",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1005",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1006",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1007",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1008",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1009",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1010",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1011",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1012",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": true,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1013",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1014",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1015",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    },
    {
      "name": "1016",
      "type": "Family",
      "status": "Occupied",
      "ac": false,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1017",
      "type": "Double",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": false
    },
    {
      "name": "1018",
      "type": "Single",
      "status": "Available",
      "ac": true,
      "tv": false,
      "ref": true
    }
  ]
}

$("#roomTypeSelect").on('change', function() {
  updateTableView()
});
$('#checkAvailable, #checkAC, #checkTV, #checkRef').on('click', function(e) {
  updateTableView(e);
});

function updateTableView(e) {
  roomType = $('#roomTypeSelect option:selected').text();
  var checkAvailable = $('#checkAvailable').prop('checked');
  
  var checks = {
    ac: $('#checkAC').prop('checked'),
    tv: $('#checkTV').prop('checked'),
    ref: $('#checkRef').prop('checked')
  };
  var lists = $.grep(dataArray.rooms, function(item) {
    var filter = true;
    if (roomType != 'Room Type')
      filter &= item.type == roomType;

    if (checkAvailable)
      filter &= item.status == 'Available';

    for (var prop in checks) {
      if (checks[prop])
        filter &= item[prop] == checks[prop]
    }

    return filter;
  });

  var items = lists.map(function(item) {
    var ac = item.ac ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var tv = item.tv ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    var ref = item.ref ? "<span style='color:green'>Yes</span>" : "<span style='color:red'>No</span>";
    return '<tr><td>' + item.name + '</td><td class="' + item.status + '">' + item.status + '</td><td>' + item.type + '</td><td>' + ac + '</td><td>' + tv + '</td><td>' + ref + '</td></tr>';
  });
  $('table.results tbody').html(items);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-0 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="text-align:left; background-color:#ccc; border-right:1px solid #aaa; padding:2rem;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select class="form-control" id="roomTypeSelect">
       <option>Room Type</option>
       <option>Single</option>
       <option>Double</option>
       <option>Family</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAvailable">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAvailable">Available</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkAC">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkAC">AC</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkTV">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkTV">TV</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkRef">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkRef">Refridgerator</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="padding:2rem">
    <table class="table results">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Room#</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
          <th scope="col">Type</th>
          <th scope="col">AC</th>
          <th scope="col">TV</th>
          <th scope="col">Refridgerator</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution.